# servlet.ChartServer is not returning the data expected

Tags: email, dashboard, report-chart

So I have a app the emails schedule reports and attaches the as excel , pdf, etc or embeds the html into the email (Note not using out of the box schedule reports)
the chart image in the reports are relative so i wrote some code to parse the html returned and my them absolute urls I grab the generated absolute urls from my debug logs this mourning. I then copy and pasted it into a browser and it worked.

I went to copy and paste the exact same links in to my browser 2 hours later and no data was show in the chartserver page. I am positive the urls are correct and if I go to a report and look at the img url it is the same as the one I generated but relative.

Example url:

```
https://<myinstance>/servlet/servlet.ChartServer?rsid=<someid>&s=5&fs=12&tfg=18&tfs=-16777216&explode=0&c=bar&cs=2&eh=yes&compo=yes&fg=-16777216&bg1=-1&bg2=-1&bgdir=2&dl1=Full%20Build%20GC&dl2=Subproject&l=1&sax=yes&Yman=no&nc=0&sd=1&scv=no&sct=no&spt=no&bd=yes&cu=USD&ab=X&u=0&vt=0&ab2=Y&u2=-1&vt2=0&vl0=Record%20Count&spoc=no&topn=no&gm=0.0&gc0=-1&gm0=1.0&gc1=-1&gm1=2.0&gc2=-1&gm2=3.0&sona=0
```

So my question, does anyone know why this might be am I not able to get this image from outside the server. Also if anyone could point me in the write direction for documentation on salesforce `chartserver` I would appreciate it as i have been unable to find any.

Comment: If the URL you have posted is the one you are trying to access then I think you are missing the host name in URL. Try this https://*instance*.Salesforce.Com/servlet/servlet.ChartServer?rsid=&s=5&fs=12&tfg=18&tfs=-16777216&explode=0&c=bar&cs=2&eh=yes&compo=yes&fg=-16777216&bg1=-1&bg2=-1&bgdir=2&dl1=Full%20Build%20GC&dl2=Subproject&l=1&sax=yes&Yman=no&nc=0&sd=1&scv=no&sct=no&spt=no&bd=yes&cu=USD&ab=X&u=0&vt=0&ab2=Y&u2=-1&vt2=0&vl0=Record%20Count&spoc=no&topn=no&gm=0.0&gc0=-1&gm0=1.0&gc1=-1&gm1=2.0&gc2=-1&gm2=3.0&sona=0 the instance will be your SFDC instance eg. emea or ap2 or cs3 or na5 etc

Comment: Thanks manjit but my instance name is in  the url https://*instance-salesforce*/servlet/servlet.ChartServer?rsid=*reportid*&s=5&fs=12&tfg=18&tfs=-16777216&explode=0&c=bar&cs=2&eh=yes&compo=yes&fg=-16777216&bg1=-1&bg2=-1&bgdir=2&dl1=Full%20Build%20GC&dl2=Subproject&l=1&sax=yes&Yman=no&nc=0&sd=1&scv=no&sct=no&spt=no&bd=yes&cu=USD&ab=X&u=0&vt=0&ab2=Y&u2=-1&vt2=0&vl0=Record%20Count&spoc=no&topn=no&gm=0.0&gc0=-1&gm0=1.0&gc1=-1&gm1=2.0&gc2=-1&gm2=3.0&sona=0 I wraped it with brackets in the question which i guess omitted it. I just tryed the same url as early worked once then 0 records on next try?